# Send Android View from server to client

Tags: android, view, client, send

I want to send a (Text)View element from a server application (='normal', non-Android Java) to the Android app on the phone and display it there.
Creating it like this on the Server...

`TextView tv=new TextView(Client.myClient);`

... gives me this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!`

`myClient` is defined like this in `Client`:

`public static Client myClient;`.

In `onCreate()` on the `Client` I wrote `myClient=this;`.

(`Server` has access to all `Client` classes, so that's not the problem.)

What am I doing wrong? Can I maybe create the TextView with another Context than the Client's, send it, and then display it on the client?
(Later I want to send arbitrary Views, that's why I don't only send the String of the TextView.)
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should send only text mean `String` from server and create `TextView` on android device. You're doing a strange thing

Comment: Taking only this problem you're certainly right but I'd like to be able to send every user interface imaginable to the phone. Using TextView is just a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you can do this: as far as I can tell `Context` is not Serializable or otherwise transferrable. You might be able to come up with a usable description language (maybe transfer the complete XML and reparse it on the client?) but not sure you can do what you've described above out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Context is not Serializable, tried that already. Okay, I'll look into how to transfer the XML - or do you instantly know how to do that?

Comment: You just create the XML just like you would for a layout and use the LayoutInflater to turn it into a view.

Comment: Spent quite a while already trying to make it work. I can turn an XML file into a view now, the issue is where to get this XML file from. Since my server program is ordinary Java I can't just put the XML file there and access it via R.layout.*. I already tried creating a new Android class, then access one of its XML files via R.layout.* and turn it into a View and then make the server take this one but I keep getting this 'stub'-error.

Comment: Ah, Android transforms the XML files in the project into a different format at compile time: the raw XML bytes are not what's being used when you inflate a View. You have to jump through special hoops to generate a View from a File with XML in it, and I'm not sure what those hoops are.

Comment: Tried to solve it the dirty way by inflating the XML file on the client, sending it to the server and back to the client. (Thinking I might later send the View from another emulated client.) Now I get this error, however: `writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.widget.RelativeLayout` Does that mean that there is no way to serialize RelativeLayout or any layouts?

Comment: Evidently not: they don't implement Serializable either.

Comment: Well, I'll do now what I initially wanted to avoid: Rewrite some of the Views I need in serializable 'light' classes with only the most important parameters. Thanks for your help anyway!